# Do some kung fu schools teach certain kung fu styles for example tiger style and panther style or all of them in one school?

Tags: kung-fu

I heard that there are kung fu styles like panther style and eagle style, but do you have to go to a certain school, temple or monastery to learn each of them? Or can you go to only one school and train all of them? I will attend Kun Yu Mountains Martial Arts Academy. How many styles will I possibly learn here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are multiple questions and half of them are local to one school.

Comment: Agreed, despite mine being one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to their website:

> In addition to teaching traditional Shaolin kung fu,we also teach other ancient arts of Chinese martial arts like Wing Chun (Professional Masters in Wingtsun lineage), Chi Kung  (Qigong), Tai Chi, Wudang, Xingyi, Bagua, Baji, Mantis boxing and Sanda (Chinese kick boxing). - See more at: http://www.chineseshaolins.com/#sthash.RqNAjwC6.dpuf

In general, most schools will teach a few different approaches, but most will focus on only a few styles unless they have a lot of good teachers who have specialized or they're more interested in keeping people interested (and paying dues) than having them learn well.

Comment: Do you guys at Kun Yu teach Tiger and Panther styles?

Comment: ^_^ I am not a member of the school. I was just quoting their website. But, off of their website, they only mention Leopard and Eagle claw styles.

Comment: @ItsMe - Here's a novel thought - Call the instructor and ask. I mean seriously, you are going to do a demanding, physical art and you don't even know what the school you have selected teaches? ::smh::